# Getting Error in storing the NSDictionary which contains some values like "<null>" in userDefaults in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
{
    deptId = 57f1fe3d3ac3aca0059d4d25;
    deptName = "Eagle Security";
    licences =         (
                    {
            "_id" = 57787880f9121e1b0516fb6b;
            name = "<null>";
        },
                    {
            "_id" = 57787881f9121e1b0516fb6c;
            name = "<null>";
        },
                    {
            "_id" = 57787883f9121e1b0516fb6d;
            name = " Mr.Apachu - SEC";
        },
                    {
            "_id" = 57787884f9121e1b0516fb6e;
            name = "Mr.John Peter - SEC";
        },
                    {
            "_id" = 578b3be488170556a2860a63;
            name = "Mr. Ramu - SEC";
        })}
```

I am trying to store this NSDictionary inside the userdefaults but it is giving me error. Can some buddy tell me how can we store it inside user defaults.

Comment: you can not store null value in NSUserdefault.

Comment: Handle this by using if let

Comment: yes you must have to check is your data empty or not with if let variable = [your_response valueforkey@"key"] {  //perfor store data } else { }

Comment: When you are saving values in NSUserDefaults. Convert the null values to empty string.

Comment: -(NSString*)replaceNullToBlankString:(id)obj
{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj];
    if ([string isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]
        || string == nil
        || ([string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && ([string isEqualToString:@"?"] || [string isEqualToString:@"(null)"] || [string isEqualToString:@"<null>"])))
    {
        return @"";
    }
    else
    {
        return (NSString*)string;
    }
}

Comment: make all `"<null>"` to `""` then you can store

Comment: I have just putted the example. the json object is very complex. i cannot go and check for every values..

Comment: If the object is big and complex, user defaults is not the place to save it anyway.

Comment: You can do one thing more. Ask the person who is working on backend to send "" rather than <null>.  or you will have to convert in your code.

Comment: in swift you can parse json data by swifty json (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

Comment: here is reference link for how to use, it helps you for checking optional values https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/libraries/how-to-parse-json-using-swiftyjson

Answer (score -2):

```
do {
        let jsonData: Data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: yourNSDictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
        let strJson:String = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
        let strJsonWithNoNull = strJson.replacingOccurrences(of: "<null>", with: "")

        let data = strJsonWithNoNull.data(using: .utf8)!

        do {
            let dictonary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any]

            if dictonary != nil
            {
                //you can store it inside user defaults
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }


    } catch  let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
```